# C++ Main Loop abstraction

Tags: c++, user-interface, c++11

Since practically every GUI out there uses a main loop to execute code (which e.g. modifies the user interface), is there a library for abstracting the actual implementation? Similar to `std::thread` it would be great to have a common interface, no matter what GUI toolkit you are using.

1 Bonus point for OpenSource and 2 for a permissive license (BSD, MIT, ...).

Comment: To modify what user interface?

Comment: GUI libraries tend to have very large APIs.  Is there value in a library that abstracts that one part and not the rest?

Comment: Maybe just write your own? You could look at an existing api for hints, such as the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qapplication.html).

Comment: @Ghost2 Well yes, but before starting I wonder whether someone else already did a decend job :)

Comment: @DrewDormann All other parts of GUI libraries are really that special, that you can hardly find common grounds (or just a base like wxWidgets). The Main Loop is the only part which is mostly working similar.

Answer (score 2):

[Zinc](http://www.psa-software.com/gui_hmi.html) is such a library, I used it many years ago so it has been around for quite some time (10+ years).

> Zinc ships with full source code as an object oriented C++ platform independent framework, and is used to implement graphical user interfaces (GUI's) for cross platform applications. Zinc is a scaleable and customizable full featured toolkit for the creation of event-driven GUI applications. Zinc is available for embedded and desktop platforms. Zinc for embedded platforms is available for real time operating systems such as Wind River's VxWorks. Zinc utilizes the look and feel of the native platform for Zinc objects.

Comment: Does this require Windows/VS? Is there a 'studio'/'designer' that works on linux?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a fast, general-purpose event loop, you could use libev http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html.

If you are instead, looking for a set of wrapper functions that give a consistent interface to the event loops of different GUIs (e.g. Gtk, Windows, Cocoa, etc), you could look at the way wxWidgets http://www.wxwidgets.org/ handles it (if it does).